# Finding the numerical radius and inner numerical radius of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, its numerical range is $W(A):=\{(\Re (x^*Ax),\Im(x^*Ax)) :x^*x=1\}\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$. $W(A)$ is a convex set.

Numerical radius is the point on $W(A)$ which is furthest away from the origin, while the inner numerical radius is the point on $W(A)$ which is closest to the origin. Let's denote the numerical radius by $R$ and the inner numerical radius by $r$. Two examples are shown below: first example is when origin is inside the numerical range and the second example is when origin is not inside the numerical range. $W(A)$ is in blue color.

[image]

How to compute the numerical radius and the inner numerical radius?

---

We can always calculate the point on $W(A)$ which is furthest along x-axis (by calculating the largest eigenvalue of the hermitian part of $A$), so one way to calculate the numerical radius is to rotate $W(A)$ and calculate that furthest point along x-axis. Then the maximum point after $360^o$ rotation will be numerical radius. But I find this method is too costly and cumbersome.

Lets denote the real and the imaginary part of $A$ by $A_H$ and $A_S$, i.e.,  $A_H=(A+A^*)/2$ and $A_S=(A-A^*)/2i$.

Then

\begin{array}{ll} R=&\underset{x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}}{\text{max}} & (x^*A_Hx)^2+(x^*A_Sx)^2\\ &\text{s.t.} & x^*x=1,\end{array}

and

\begin{array}{ll} r=&\underset{x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}}{\text{min}} & (x^*A_Hx)^2+(x^*A_Sx)^2\\ &\text{s.t.} & x^*x=1.\end{array}

Is it possible to solve such nonconvex problems? I have tried to rewrite them:

\begin{array}{ll} R=&\underset{X\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}}{\text{max}} & (\mathrm{tr}(A_HX))^2+(\mathrm{tr}(A_SX))^2\\ &\text{ s.t.} & \mathrm{tr}(X)=1\\&&X\succeq0,\end{array}

or also can rewrite as

\begin{array}{ll} R=&\underset{X\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}}{\text{max}} & \mathrm{tr}(A_HXA_HX)+\mathrm{tr}(A_SXA_SX)\\ &\text{ s.t.} & \mathrm{tr}(X)=1\\&&X\succeq0.\end{array}

In last two optimization problems, I have removed $\mathrm{rank}(X)=1$ constraint, because there are some methods to deal with it later as long as I can solve these two problems.